# Which Prism is geared towards desktop apps "Xamarin Prism" or "WPF Prism" or "UWP Prism"?

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms, prism

On the prismlibrary documentation it shows WPF (lagacy 6).  If I want to develop/refactor an app to the newest technology should I use Xamarin.Forms with Prism or UWP Prism?  (right now it is in WPF but still in beta, I could change it)  The documentation isn't clear.

The app is a desktop app.  Calls are made to the backend through a mediatR.

Comment: What's wrong with `Prism.Wpf`? This is not deprecated but I believe Prism for UWP is. Whether to develop a WPF or a Xamarin.Forms app depends on whether you target Windows-only or other platforms as well.

Comment: I'd say, you don't have a choice in the first place.. android or ios -> xamarin, windows 7 -> wpf, only for windows 10 you could even chose between wpf and uwp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is not deprecated. The "Legacy" section of the docs is just that the docs are overly verbose and not really easy for us to keep them up to date so some of the docs still very much apply while other sections don't really apply at all for Prism 7 (mainly around Dependency Injection).

UWP is currently not being supported by the Prism team. Prism 6 for UWP had a number of flaws and needed a lot fixed. We attempted a merge with Template 10 but that ended up being worse for us. As of right now we need one or more companies who are willing to help sponsor the initiative to rewrite Prism for UWP as it is simply too much work for "in our spare time" when neither Brian or I have a business need for UWP support.